# Combinatorics: In how many ways can people have the same birthdate

Tags: combinatorics

For the question

> If $4$ people are asked their numeric birthdates (not months) and the results written down one at a time, $31^4$ different sequences might be created. In how many of these is there a repeated number.

I don't know what the right answer is, but I attempted it like this.
$4$ people have same birthdate OR $3$ people have same birthdate OR $2$ people have the same birthdate

In how many ways can $4$ people have the same birthdate: $31 * 1 * 1 * 1$
In how many ways can $3$ people have the same birthdate: $31 * 1 * 1 * 30$
In how many ways can $2$ people have the same birthdate: $31 * 1 * 30 * 29$

Then add the all the ways possible to together $31 + 930 + 26970 = 27931$. Can someone tell me if this is right? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not considering the numbers of ways to choose which two people have the same birthday.  You also have a problem with the case where there are two pairs of people with the same birthdays, but not all four have the same birthday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All permutations = $31^4$

All permutations where birthdates are different = <sub>31</sub>P<sub>4</sub>

Therefore all permutations where birthdates do not repeat: $31^4$-<sub>31</sub>P<sub>4</sub>

What do you think about our professor?

Comment: I would think this would be a combination problem because the order of the birthdates would not matter

Answer (score 1):

The correct approach to solve the problem is to subtract from the overall number of combinations these without repeating dates:
$$31^4-31 \cdot 30\cdot29\cdot 28.
$$